# how to write clang format settings?

Tags: clang, visual-studio-code, clang-format

In vscode, I am having this `.clang-format`:

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
    AfterEnum: true
    AfterStruct: true
    AfterClass: true
    AfterControlStatement: Always
    AfterFunction: true
    AfterNamespace: true
    AfterObjCDeclaration: true
    AfterUnion: true
    AfterExternBlock: false
    BeforeCatch: false
    BeforeElse: false
    BeforeLambdaBody: false
    BeforeWhile: false
```

And

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

But when I try to write the file:

```
YAML:3:17: error: Found invalid tab character in indentation
        AfterEnum: true
YAML:3:2: error: Map value must not be empty
        AfterEnum: true
        ^~~~~~~~~
```

The tab before `AfterEnum: true` is taken from the official documentation on [clang formatting](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), so what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use (exactly) 2 spaces for the indentation, not a `tab` character. The official documentation does not specify this, but it is the format you get from `clang-format -dump-config`.